# How to deal with *.snap files if it shows "cannot remove active revision of snap" error?

Tags: package-management, snap, spotify

`mount | grep snap` output:

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/spotify_5.snap on /snap/spotify/5 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_3887.snap on /snap/core/3887 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
```

`sudo snap remove spotify --revision 5` output:

```
error: cannot remove "spotify": cannot remove active revision 5 of snap "spotify"
```

Same is the case with the other snap file. I have successfully removed 2 similar snap files using the snap remove command. It's these two files that cause problems.

Answer (score 3):

The command `snap remove` when used alone will just remove the given snap and all of its data. When used with `--revision` it will only remove a specific revision but there's a constraint where it cannot remove an active revision (the one that is being used at the time). If you want to remove a snap completely simply don't use `--revision`.